# How to clone a local Git repository using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, git-clone, git-fetch

I'm trying to clone a Git repository that resides on my local drive into a new folder. So far, I've tried several modules, from which [creationix/js-git](https://github.com/creationix/js-git) seemed to be the most promising one.

The code to fetch I use is:

```
  var source = '...',
      target = '...';

  var remoteRepository = git.remote('file://' + source),
      localRepository = git.repo(target);

  var options = {
    onProgress: function (progress) {
      console.log(progress);
    }
  };

  localRepository.fetch(remoteRepository, options, function (err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    console.log('Done');
  });
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, as `js-git` complains about an unknown URL format, which relates to the `file://` protocol being used. The same error appears when I remove the `file://` portion.

I also tried to change `git.remote` to `git.repo` (as it's not an actual remote), but then I get:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'discover'
```

So, apparently `js-git` does not support fetching from local repositories (or I was not able to find out how to do it).

Does anyone…

- …either know how to solve this using `js-git`,
- or can suggest a viable alternative?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Why can't you just use child_process.exec and a command line option ?

Comment: Because it shall run on OS X, Linux and Windows, and I don't have the target machines under my control, and I'm not too sure whether an end user will be able to correctly (!) setup Git, especially on Windows.